# Python: Index Out Of Range

Tags: python, list, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm new to python and this may be a simple one line or one character answer but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I have a list I want to iterate through and check if the element in the index after the current index is the same and delete it if it is.

```
while i < len(list):
    if list[i] == list[i+1]:
        del list[i];
    i+=1;
```

I know the problem is coming from "if list[i] == list[i+1]:" when I get to end of the list "list[i+1]" will be out of range of the index. The problem is that I don't know how to stop the code when it gets to that point where it goes out of range

Comment: Don't name the list you're iterating over `list`, that is an inbuilt function for python

Comment: Make first line as while (i+1) < len(list):

Comment: @John Arano Check this out: http://ideone.com/ocUjHu

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `list` is the built-in function of python, so you should never use it for the name of your variables.

And to your problems itself. The fix for your error is simple:

```
while i < (len(_list) - 1):
    if _list[i] == _list[i+1]:
        del _list[i]
    i+=1;
```

The reason for the IndexError is that at the last iteration `i` is already the last index and you are trying to get the element at the `i+1` position.

Comment: There are no semicolons in python.

Comment: I've really just copied the OP code and fixed the first line. Fixed that in the answer, didnt notice.

Comment: @Nurzhan - Yes there are. They're just not necessary at the end of a logical line.

Comment: variables starting with '_' are internally used by python or for some standard modules, better not to have such names.